# What is the default retry policy for the Microsoft Graph SDK (Java)? (Error code: ApplicationThrottled)

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

The following 429 error occurred while trying to get Outlook resources using the Microsoft Graph Java SDK.

```
"com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: ApplicationThrottled
    Error message: Application is over its MailboxConcurrency limit.
```

When I looked it up, I noticed that a mailboxConcurrent error occurs when multiple requests are sent at once. I see the error as a result of the repeated buildup of existing requests on the server during the retry process because my code only sends one request at a time.

What I'm curious about here is that if I use Graph SDK, I guess I'll look at the Retry-After value in the response header and try again after that time, but isn't it?

I'd like to know the basic retry strategy for Microsoft Graph Java SDK.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 1):

The basic implementation is hidden in Kiota middleware. You can overwrite the retry handler [option for each request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v6.md#per-request-options).

The source code for the retry handler option is in GitHub repo:

https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-java/blob/main/components/http/okHttp/src/main/java/com/microsoft/kiota/http/middleware/options/RetryHandlerOption.java

https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-java/blob/main/components/http/okHttp/src/main/java/com/microsoft/kiota/http/middleware/RetryHandler.java

It handles status codes 429, 503 and 504.